# How to achieve this kind of url routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

i want to achieve url routing something like `www.example.com/alicia`
suppose alicia is not a class name or method name just something like passing data in url and with some class i want to access this and want to use it for further process.How i can use it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Codeigniter's built-in routing, the file `route.php` is located in your `config` folder.

there you can add:

```
$route['alicia'] = 'welcome/index/something';
$route['alicia/:any'] = 'welcome/index/someotherthing/$1';
```

then in your controller, for example `welcome` you just create a function like:

```
public function index($page = null){
  if($page=='something'){
    // do what you need to do, for example load a view:
    $this->load->view('allaboutalicia');
  }
  elseif ($page=='someotherthing'){
      // here you can read in data from url (www.example.com/alicia/2017
      $year=$this->uri->segment(2);  // you need to load the helper url previously
  }else{
  // do some other stuff
  }
}
```

documentation on **[routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#uri-routing)** and on **[urlhelper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)**

**edit after comment:**

in case your uri segment is representing a variable, like a username, then you should use a uri scheme like `www.example.com/user/alice` and create your route like:

```
$route['user/:any'] = 'welcome/index/user';
```

then in your controller `welcome`

```
public function index($page=null){
  if($page=='user'){
    // do what you need to do with that user
    $user=$this->uri->segment(2);  // you need to load the helper url 
  }
  else{
    // exception
  }
}
```

Comment: This routing method would require distinct rules for each name that you might want to route. Not sure, but I got the feeling the OP was looking for something that would work for any arbitrary name you might specify. Sort of like twitter.com/username

Answer (score 0):

This could be tricky because you don't want to break any existing urls that already work.

If you are using Apache, you can set up a mod_rewrite rule that takes care to exclude each of your controllers that is NOT some name.

Alternatively, you could create a [remap method](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls) in your base controller.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function _remap($method)
    {
        echo "request for $method being handled by " . __METHOD__;
    }
}
```

You could write logic in that method to examine the requested $method or perhaps look at $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] to decide what you want to do. This can be a bit tricky to sort out but is probably a good way to get started.

Another possibility, if you can think of some way to distinguish these urls from your other urls, would be to use the [routing functionality of codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=routing) and define a pattern matching rule in the routes.php file that points these names to some controller which handles them.

I believe that the default_controller will be a factor in this. Any controller/method situations that actually correspond to a controller::method class should be handled by that controller::method. Any that do not match will, I believe, be assigned to your default_controller:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```